# Refresh image using saved paths from database

Tags: wpf, image, dataset, refresh

Hi. This is `C#` in `Visual Studio 2010`. I uploaded an image path using the following method. The path was successfully stored in the database and the uploaded image displayed. However the uploaded image persists on showing despite my navigation of other records. Other images are not retrieved, only the uploaded one stays on. I tried refilling the dataset again after saving but it gives error: "URI is empty". Other text fields refresh successfully except the image by the path(photo_text.Text).

```
private void uploadPhoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.FileName = ".jpg";
    ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures";
    ofd.Title = "Select passport photo to upload";
    ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.JPG)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        pixx.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofd.FileName));
        photo_text.Text = ofd.FileName;
    }
}
```

Second method:

```
if (studentsDataSetstudentTableAdapter.Update(studentsDataSet.student) > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your data has been saved!", "DATA STATUS", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    studentsDataSetstudentTableAdapter.Fill(studentsDataSet.student);
    pixx.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(photo_text.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the image properties of the image where there is the source binding to the data from the data where there are options,the 'mode' should be set to "**TwoWay**" and 'UpdateSourceTrigger' to "**PropertyChanged**"
the image will change each time you flip through the records!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. When I load the image appears and writes well. But when I stand in another register the image is the same for everyone. 
In the XAML I made indicating Robert Omete but no image appears blank when I put Mode = TwoWay or OneWayToSource.

Load Image Code:

```
    private void BtnCargarFoto_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OD = new OpenFileDialog();
        OD.Filter = "jpg(*.jpg)|*.jpg|png(*.png)|*.png|gif(*.gif)|*.gif|bmp(*.bmp)|*.bmp|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (OD.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (Stream stream = OD.OpenFile())
            {
                //bitCoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                //    BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                bitCoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                ImgFoto.Source = bitCoder.Frames[0];
            }
            System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(OD.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            foto = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length.ToString())];
            fs.Read(foto, 0, foto.Length);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
            <Image x:Name="ImgFoto" Source="{Binding Foto, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Height="127" Margin="38,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176">
            </Image>
```